# What is the best way to call a different entity in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

If I wanted to "progress" to another entity if certain requirements were met in the current entity what would the best way to do this be? Through direct instantiation of the entity or should I call it as a component/procedure? For example;

```
begin
displayChoice : process (i_Reset, i_StartStop, i_SW)
begin

case displayChoice is
    when (i_SW = "1000") =>
        i_D4 <= 0 ;
        process is                -- this is where I want to call the other entity in
        begin                     -- so if i_SW is 1000 then D4 is 0 and so I want to call to my next 
            displayD3;            -- entity to deal with D3
        end process;
        
    when (i_SW = "0100") =>
        i_D4 <= 1;
        i_D3 <= 7;
        
    when (i_SW = "1100") =>
        i_D4 <= 2;
        i_D3 <= 14;
       
    when (i_SW = "0010") =>
        i_D4 <= 3;
        i_D3 <= 8;
        
    when (i_SW = "1010") =>
        i_D4 <= 4;
        i_D3 <= counter value;
           
    when (i_SW = "0001") =>
        i_D4 <= 6;
        i_D3 <= 0 ;
        
    when (i_SW = "1001") =>
        i_D4 <= 7;
        i_D3 <=  0;
    
    when others =>   
        i_D4 <= 0;
        i_D3 <= 0;
    
    end case;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

So, my question is where (in this code) and how (direct instantiation or component/procedure or another way entirely?) do I "actiate" the next entity?

[This is my block diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ1e6.png)

Comment: Entities are blocks of hardware. You don't "call" them any more than you "call" a chip on a PCB. Entities are always there. It is up to you as the hardware designer to connect them up in the right way to meet your requirements. It seems like you don't really know what hardware you are implementing. You must always know what hardware you are implementing. I recommend you draw the circuit or block diagram first. (Even experienced VHDL users would draw a block diagram before starting coding. And they certainly know roughly what hardware they are implementing.)

Comment: Hi @MatthewTaylor thank you for your response, as I'm sure you can tell I am a basic novice at this. I have now embedded my basic block diagram. Sorry I didn't include in the first instance.

Comment: Direct instantiation and components have their uses and advantages. Direct instantiation allows the compiler to syntax check against the entity being used, so errors are often picked up earlier. It also removes the need to have what is essentially the same code twice, and maintain it twice. Components are usually required when the component being instantiated is another language or netlist, the entity doesnt exist or black boxed. But in the mojority of cases, if all code if VHDL, then direct instantiation will suffice.

Comment: @Tricky thank you for your response, that helps me a lot.

Comment: So which of those blocks in the block diagram is this code supposed to implement?

Comment: Possibly related... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251164/vhdl-multipliers/15251764#15251764